# Snipping HTML with DOMDocument outputs invalid characters

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'm using the DOMDocument class in PHP to snip out a few lines of text. The text here is a large block of HTML which was entered by a WYSIWYG editor.

The code I'm using to do is like this:

```
$body_string .= '<p class="summary">';

$domd = new DOMDocument();
$domd->encoding = 'utf-8';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML(utf8_decode($post['content']));
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$domx = new DOMXPath($domd);
$items = $domx->query("//p[position() = 1] | //div[position() = 1]");

$body_string .= substr($items->item(0)->textContent, 0, 230);
$body_string .= '</p>
```

But, when the string has special characters like the ellipsis or the curly quotes, they get turned into a question mark.

So a text like this:

> We know, TED talks can sometimes feel a little… overblown. While there
>   are loads of great talks; some of them go nowhere and don’t seem to
>   add much to your life at all. To make things worse… there are a lot of
>   TED talks and it’s hard to tell

turns into this:

> We know, TED talks can sometimes feel a little? overblown. While there
>   are loads of great talks; some of them go nowhere and don?t seem to
>   add much to your life at all. To make things worse? there are a lot of
>   TED talks and it?s hard to tell

This happens only if I use the DOMDocument class. Without it the characters don't get converted to the question marks.

How can I fix this? The HTML document already has a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">` in the `<head>`

Comment: can you provide an example of this string that can replicate this problem of yours?

Comment: @Ghost I'm not sure what you mean... See the text above?

Comment: im trying to replicate this on my env, what i mean is  the contents of `$post['content']`. but anyways, only the thing that i can do here is to guess.

Comment: @Ghost See the quoted text. That is in the `$post['content']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't seem to reproduce that one, instead try this workaround:

```
$body_string .= '<p class="summary">';

$domd = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($post['content'], 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
libxml_clear_errors();

$domx = new DOMXPath($domd);
$items = $domx->query("//p[position() = 1] | //div[position() = 1]");

$body_string .= substr($items->item(0)->textContent, 0, 230);
$body_string .= '</p>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CR5nGJ)

<sub>Closest thing reproducible.</sub>

Comment: Can you maybe explain what was I doing wrong? I still don't understand what I was doing wrong... :)

Comment: @maxxon15 what it basically did is first, since `->loadHTML()` defaults to `ISO-8859-1` it messes up those entities. so before loading them, the workaround is to convert them to html entities instead.

Comment: @maxxon15 there is a very eloquent answer here on SO regarding that part. i think its hakre's answer but i can't find the post. sorry if i cannot explain well as english isn't really my first language

Comment: Oh I see. So, merely setting the `$domd->encoding = 'utf-8';` won't work. I have to explicitly convert the html with the `mb_convert_encoding` function after that. Right?

Comment: @maxxon15 yes basically the conversion is before feeding it into `->loadHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Setting `DOMDocument::encoding` is only useful for changing the encoding when printing out the DOMDocument as a string, so won't have any effect here.

Similarly, setting 'utf-8' in the `DOMDocument` constructor has no effect, as it is only used when creating a new document from scratch, not when parsing an existing document.

The HTML parser needs to know what the encoding of the posted content is, like this:

```
$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML('<meta charset="utf-8">' . $post['content']);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
```